# How to report Cronbach's alpha for referent-shift scale (before or after aggregation?)

Tags: reliability, measurement-error, aggregation, cronbachs-alpha

I have a study variable that is measured at the individual level and then aggregated and to the group level. My hypothesis testing is conducted at the group level. 
I used an 8-item referent-shift measure of team psychological capital.

When calculating and reporting the coefficient alpha, should I be looking at it across individual level scores, or averaging (aggregating) each item across each team, and then calculating the coefficient alphas across aggregated item scores.

That is, I can find the average value of item 1 within team 1, then the average value of item 2 within team 1 etc.  I will then have one value for each scale item per team.  I will then calculate the alpha based on n=94 teams. Alternatively, I could leave everything at the individual level, and calculate it that way across all individuals within my sample (n=456 individual team members).

I would think I should measure it at the group level, since I am conducting my analyses as the group level. That is, I should be most concerned about the level of measurement error in the aggregated team-level scale, right?   If I calculate it at the team level, I get alpha=0.92, and if I calculate it at the individual level, I get alpha=0.86.  At the end of the day, they're both good alphas, but I still want to report the correct number.

Also, in case this is important in answering the question,
I have calculated ICC(1), ICC(2) and rwg for the scale means (rather than on an item by item basis) and they are acceptable for aggregating the scale **means** to the group level.

Thank you in advance!

Note: Referent-shift measure means that the referent of the scale is the team rather than the individual.  So the individual-referent psychological capital item might be **I** am optimistic about my work. The team-referent psychological capital item would be **Members of my team** are optimistic about their work. See  Functional relations among constructs in the same content domain at different levels of analysis: A typology of composition models. Chan, David Journal of Applied Psychology, Vol 83(2), Apr 1998, 234-246.

Edit: While the scale is measured at the individual level, analyses are conducted at the group level (after aggregation).  Hence my confusion over whether I should report individual level alpha or group level alpha...  Group level alpha would be found by aggregating each individual item (find average within-group value for each item and then calculate alpha based on that).

Comment: I think you want it at the individual level. Alpha is a measure of test reliability, and the test is given to individuals.

Comment: What does referent mean?  Is it a real owrd?  Could you mean "reference"?

Answer (score -1):

I've seen people reporting the two. I don't think there's one golden standard. The alpha at the team level is not too informative, as it is much important to see the ICC2.